# Проблема взаимодействия Jquery и PHP, MySQL

Tags: jquery, php, mysql

Есть ссылка вида `http://www.site.ru/message.php?id=184&tab=0`. Когда на нее нажимаешь PHP получает `$_GET['id']` и посылает запрос к базе данных MYSQL, чтобы получить сообщение с нужным id.

Попробовал сделать, чтобы выезжало модальное окно (bootstrap, jQuery), при нажатии на ссылку: `http://www.site.ru/message.php?id=184&tab=0`. Окно благополучно выезжает, только PHP не получает id и не передает запрос к БД MySQL и модальное окно пустое.

Подскажите как решить проблему? Чтобы при нажатие на ссылку выезжало модальное окно и PHP успевал получить `$_GET['id']`, отправить запрос к БД и заполнить данные в модальном окне?

```
<!-- ВЫВОД СООБЩЕНИЯ -->
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $a = $_GET['id'];
        echo "<h1>$a</h1>";

        $query = "SELECT username, subject, message, DATE_FORMAT(created, '%d-%m-%Y %T') AS `date` FROM messages WHERE id='$a'";
        $result = mysql_unbuffered_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

        $from = $row['username'];
        $subject = $row['subject'];
        $date = $row['date'];
        $message = $row['message'];

        foreach ($row as $key => $value) 
        {
            echo "$key => $value<br>";
        }
    }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" style="display:none;">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h3>Сообщение</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Отправитель: <?php  echo ("<b>$from</b>"); ?></p>
            <p>Тема: <?php echo ("<b>$subject</b>"); ?></p>
            <p>Отправлено: <?php echo ("<b>$date</b>"); ?></p>
            <hr>
            <p><?php echo ("<b>$message</b>"); ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</a>
            <a href="message.php?tab=1" class="btn btn-primary">Ответить</a>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- ВЫВОД СООБЩЕНИЯ -- КОНЕЦ -->
![alt text][1]![alt text][2]
```

Comment: Видимо GET запрос просто не срабатывает, а сразу идет вызов модального окна((

Comment: Данные в обработчик отправляете Ajax-запросом?

Comment: Нет, сейчас добавлю код.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой JavaScript (jQuery) код мне нужно добавить, чтобы задумка заработала?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас тут возможна SQL-иньекция. 
Либо экранируйте введённые данные (id), либо используйте [PDO prepare statements](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Во-вторых, вот примерный код на jQuery, который поможет решить вашу проблему:

```
//обработчик события нажатия на ссылку <a href="#" class="show-comment" id="241">Просмотреть комментарий</a>
$('.show-comment').click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); //не вызываем дефолтное действие события (чтобы страница не скроллилась вверх)
    var url = '/messages.php?id=' + $(this).attr('id'); //формируем url, на который будем слать запрос
    $.get(url, function(data){ //делаем GET-запрос к серверу
        // вставляем ответ в модальную форму и показываем её
        $('#myModal').html(data).show();
    });
});
```

А в скрипте message.php выводим только то, что должно быть в блоке myModal.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но у меня файл message.php сильно перегружен, там уже более 500 строк кода, придется все разделить!

Comment: Просто я в jQuery и Ajax запросах не силен. Добавил к ссылкам class=\"show-comment\", так они генерируются с помощью PHP, затем добавил jQuery код, который Вы запостили выше, но модальное окно открывается пустое.

Comment: А к ссылками id добавили?

Comment: Попробуйте самое простое - ту часть JS, которая отвечает за всплытие модального окна, поместите в DOM-ready. Т.е. так:

    $(document).ready(function(){
        // код модального окна
    });

Comment: Сейчас попробую создать отдельный PHP файл, к которому будет отправляться GET запрос.

Comment: Конечно, к ссылкам id я добавил!